# calling completableFuture in while loop for byteArrayOutputStream not working properly

Tags: java, io, stream, completable-future

CompletableFuture works fine with simple asynchronous task but i have tried same in while loop when reading a file and writing to multiple files as per below code:-

```
BufferedInputStream bin = null;
ReadableByteChannel channel = null;
int bufferSize = 1048576;
int readBufferSize = 1024*4;
java.nio.ByteBuffer byteBuffer = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(readBufferSize);
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\Harisingh\\myfile.txt"));

bin = new BufferedInputStream(is,bufferSize);
channel = Channels.newChannel(bin);
int retryCnt = 0;
ByteArrayOutputStream baOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bufferSize);
int totalBytes=0;
int itrCount=0;
int maxIterateCnt = 1;
int len;
//primary location file path
BufferedOutputStream bFout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Harisingh\\FileUpload\\primary.txt")));
//secondary location file path
FileUploadMultiLocator fileUploadMultiLocator = new FileUploadMultiLocator("fileserver0",new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\Harisingh\\SecondaryPath\\Secondary1.txt"))));

 if(bufferSize > readBufferSize){
      maxIterateCnt = bufferSize/readBufferSize;
 }
while((len=channel.read(byteBuffer))>=0) 
            {
                itrCount++;
                totalBytes+=len;
                baOS.write(byteBuffer.array(),0,len);
                if(itrCount>=maxIterateCnt)
                {
                    //Writing to one file on primary location only
                    try{
                        bFout.write(baOS.toByteArray(),0,totalBytes);
                    }catch(Exception se)
                    {
                    }
                  //sending baOS for writing to other files on secondary locations with fileUploadMultiLocator runnable class
                    createCompletableFutureTask(baOS, totalBytes, fileUploadMultiLocator);
                    totalBytes=0;
                    baOS.reset();
                    itrCount=0;
                }
                byteBuffer.clear();
            }
```

createCompletableFutureTask(baOS, totalBytes, fileUploadMultiLocator) method code as like below:-

```
public static void createCompletableFutureTask(ByteArrayOutputStream baOS, int totalBytes, FileUploadMultiLocator fileUploadMultiLocator){
    // Submit Task 1
     CompletableFuture<Integer> f1 = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
         try {
             fileUploadMultiLocator.baOS.write(baOS.toByteArray(), 0, totalBytes);
             fileUploadMultiLocator.setTotalBytes(totalBytes);
             new Thread(fileUploadMultiLocator).start();                    
         } catch (Exception e) {
         }
         System.out.println("Task 1 completed");
         return 5;
     });
}
```

I think As we know that completableFuture execute asynchronously and in this case i am sending baOS in while loop while reading a file so due to threading in while loop, task don't have control of baOS so it is able to write only some bytes not all on secondary location

FYI i would like to inform you that if i add

> f1.get()

code in createCompletableFutureTask method then it works fine but it works as synchronously that means primary & secondary location both writing will be completed at same time due to synchronous behavior.

But i want to primary location writing should be done by main thread synchronously and secondary location writing should be done by completableFuture task asynchronously in background. Can you please help me to achieve this?